# Syntax error after Xcode 7.3 update

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

yesterday i installed the new Xcode 7.3 and my problem started.

I have to make many changes which comes with swift 3.
many changes I solved with the "auto correction" of Xcode.

But there are two things, which can't be solve automatically:

**Problem 1**
[image]

**Problem 2**

```
 for ( var x = 1; x < self.ACData.count; x ++ ) {
```

But i should do this:

[image]

If I apply the correction I get this:

```
for ( x in 2 ..< self.ACData.count ) {
```

and that makes me a syntax error.
Can anyone help me please ? :)

**UPDATE**

```
let app:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
  for oneEvent in app.scheduledLocalNotifications! {
    let notification: AnyObject = oneEvent
    let userInfoCurrent = notification.userInfo as! [NSObject: AnyObject]
    if userInfoCurrent["UUID"] == nil {
      app.cancelLocalNotification(notification as! UILocalNotification)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1:

Don't downcast, not necessary. You can enter a string for the NSObject, so just write this:

```
let userInfoCurrent = notification.userInfo!
```

Problem 2:

Remove the brackets. That's really all you have to do to fix it, don't write:

```
for ( x in 2 ..< self.ACData.count )
```

That's not the correct swift way, it should be:

```
for x in 2 ..< self.ACData.count {
```

Update:

Based on the code shown above I think the best way to do this is:

```
let app:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
for oneEvent in app.scheduledLocalNotifications! {
    let notification: AnyObject = oneEvent
    guard let userInfoCurrent = notification.userInfo,
          let uuid = userInfoCurrent["UUID"] else {
          app.cancelLocalNotification(notification as! UILocalNotification)        
          return //or continue, don't know if you want to keep looping after this
    }
    // Do something with UUID if it's not necessary you can update the code as follows:
    // guard let userInfoCurrent = notification.userInfo where userInfoCurrent["UUID"] != nil else {
}
```

I hope this works

Comment: if i use your solution for problem 1 i get the error: `Ambiguous use of 'userInfo'`. problem 2 can be solve like your way :)

Comment: Hmm weird. What about `let userInfoCurrent = notification.userInfo as! [NSObject: AnyObject]`

Comment: Hm damn, I generally unwrap these things in a guard check so I am not really sure how to satisfy the compiler when trying to downcast it and me not having updated my mac to El Capitan makes this incredibly hard ^^;
Did you already try to unwrap the values in a guard or if let check?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:**

`scheduledLocalNotifications` is clearly declared as `[UILocalNotification]?`.
The annotation to `AnyObject` is very bad.

Basically annotations are not needed because the compiler can infer the type

```
let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
if let localNotifications = app.scheduledLocalNotifications {
    for notification in localNotifications {
      let userInfoCurrent = notification.userInfo as! [String: AnyObject]
      if userInfoCurrent["UUID"] == nil {
        app.cancelLocalNotification(notification)
      }
    }
}
```

or still simpler

```
let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
if let localNotifications = app.scheduledLocalNotifications {
  for notification in localNotifications {
    if notification.userInfo?["UUID"] == nil {
      app.cancelLocalNotification(notification)
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem 2:**

Unlike Objective-C parentheses around `if` / `for` / `while` conditions are not required in Swift and even could cause problems like in your case.

Just remove the parentheses

```
for x in 2 ..< self.ACData.count {
```